# Changing An Element In Foreach Vs For

Tags: powershell

why do I get different outputs below depending on whether I use for or foreach?
With a foreach, when you change the value of each element, aren't you changing it's reference? I would have thought doing $row = "d" would make that element point to "d" but apparently it doesn't do that, it's as if $row is just a copy.

```
[Collections.Generic.List[String]]$list = New-Object '[Collections.Generic.List[String]]'
$list.Add("a")
$list.Add("b")
$list.Add("c")

#foreach ($row in $list)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $list.Count; $i++)
{
#$row = "d"
$list[$i] = "d"
}

Write-Host $list

<#
Output: with foreach: "a b c"
with for: "d d d"
#>
```

Comment: what do you mean? There is no C# in my code, it's pure Powershell.

Comment: My mistake. All references to `[Collections.Generic.List[String]]` I saw were c# related. Perhaps my powershell version is lower than yours.

Comment: @Matt C# is just a language (like Powershell) which targets the .NET framework. Collections.Generic.List[String] is just a class in .NET which you can use in C# (Collections.Generic.List<String>) or Powershell ([Collections.Generic.List[String]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `foreach` (and `ForEach-Object`) results in the element inside the loop being a copy. You can change it inside the loop but it's gone once you go out of scope.

Comment: This really is a matter of Scope and understanding how child scopes work. I would have liked to see something more about that. i.e. tell them to `get-help about_scopes` or provide a [link to the technet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) that talks about scopes.

Comment: I think it has to do with a bit more than just scopes though. If the variable were local to the block (and it is), but it was a reference like the poster expected it to be, than the scope wouldn't matter because it would still update the referenced object. The fact that it's a copy is the real issue here, I think.

Comment: @briantist It wouldn't updated the referenced object because the reference which gets copied ($row) gets assigned a brand new reference (the pointer which points to the string object "d"), leaving the original reference untouched.
Then since its scope is only within the foreach loop, it gets garbage collected and the original object which was copied remains the same.

Comment: @briantist Things would be different if I was accessing a member of the object and updating that, in that case the variable is not assigned a new reference and the original object's member would be updated and be available after the foreach loop finished.